# how do you make it so there is a time on "ReadKey"

Tags: c#, console

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set console window size
            Console.SetWindowSize(32, 32); // console size

            int playerX = 0; // initial x position of the player
            int playerY = 0; // initial y position of the player

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear(); // clear the console screen

                // Draw the game board
                for (int y = 0; y < 30; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
                    {
                        if (x == playerX && y == playerY)
                        {
                            Console.Write("P"); // draw the player
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("."); // draw empty space
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                // user input
                ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
                ConsoleKey key = keyInfo.Key;

                // Move the player on user input
                if (key == ConsoleKey.A && playerX > 0)
                {
                    playerX--;
                }
                else if (key == ConsoleKey.D && playerX < 29)
                {
                    playerX++;
                }
                else if (key == ConsoleKey.W && playerY > 0)
                {
                    playerY--;

                }
                else if (key == ConsoleKey.S && playerY < 29)
                {
                    playerY++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i am trying to make it in my c# console mini game i can't hold down my key binds so it moves even when i relise the key, for example when i run it now and i hold down S it will do SSSSSSSSSSSS then when i relise the key the P will keep going down until it has writen all the S i gave it. How do i stop this so you can't hold down the P i need to press it again and again. hope someone understands or can try it and see what i mean

Comment: What is the P ?

Comment: You could try flushing the input buffer at the *end* of your loop: `while (Console.KeyAvailable) Console.ReadKey(true);`

Comment: I copied you code and i dont see your issue.
The only thing i see, is that it doesn't clear the console.

Answer (score 0):

I think I Understand your issue the console applications and method ReadKey is not meant to catch inputs like games do.. therefore game engines exists..

The issue you are facing is due to the keyboard repeat feature e.g.
If I hold K it will not send single K being held down to the console app but rather a bunch of K in a row like so : kkkkkkkkkkkkk

I have a workaround that might help add delay after reading a key this should ignore the autorepeat function thus making the user to repeat keystroke for every move instance
This isn't a perfect solution, as it changes the responsiveness of the game

But I think for consoleApp it is the best solution:

```
using System;
using System.Threading; // Import the Threading namespace

namespace ConsoleGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set console window size
            Console.SetWindowSize(32, 32); // console size

            int playerX = 0; // initial x position of the player
            int playerY = 0; // initial y position of the player

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear(); // clear the console screen

                // Draw the game board
                for (int y = 0; y < 30; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
                    {
                        if (x == playerX && y == playerY)
                        {
                            Console.Write("P"); // draw the player
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("."); // draw empty space
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                // User input
                ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true); // Use ReadKey(true) to prevent echoing the character
                ConsoleKey key = keyInfo.Key;

                // Move the player on user input
                if (key == ConsoleKey.A && playerX > 0)
                {
                    playerX--;
                }
                else if (key == ConsoleKey.D && playerX < 29)
                {
                    playerX++;
                }
                else if (key == ConsoleKey.W && playerY > 0)
                {
                    playerY--;
                }
                else if (key == ConsoleKey.S && playerY < 29)
                {
                    playerY++;
                }

                // Introduce a small delay to mitigate key auto-repeat
                Thread.Sleep(100); // Adjust the delay as needed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use `Console.ReadKey(true)`
The `true` argument suppresses the character from being echoed to the console, making the input handling cleaner

Alternatively a better solution for a consoleAPP would be to convert the game to be a **turnbased** and requiring the user to input a command to move a one square:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.SetWindowSize(32, 32); // Set console window size

            int playerX = 0; // Initial x position of the player
            int playerY = 0; // Initial y position of the player

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear(); // Clear the console screen

                // Draw the game board
                for (int y = 0; y < 30; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
                    {
                        if (x == playerX && y == playerY)
                        {
                            Console.Write("P"); // Draw the player
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("."); // Draw empty space
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                // Prompt the user for input
                Console.WriteLine("Enter move (W, A, S, D) + Enter: ");
                string command = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper(); // Read the command and convert to uppercase

                // Move the player based on user input
                if (command == "A" && playerX > 0)
                {
                    playerX--;
                }
                else if (command == "D" && playerX < 29)
                {
                    playerX++;
                }
                else if (command == "W" && playerY > 0)
                {
                    playerY--;
                }
                else if (command == "S" && playerY < 29)
                {
                    playerY++;
                }

                // The console will clear and redraw the board at the start of the next loop iteration
            }
        }
    }
}
```